# What is best among clustered index scan vs non-clustered index seek

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I'm trying to figure out which is best option to choose, my primary requirement is to reduce the IO.

- I have a table with 500M records, where the below mentioned query is choosing the default clustered index scan on the table.
- I tried to create a covering non-clustered index but it still choses the clustered index scan as default. so I have forced it to use the covering index and my observations are the logical reads came down from 3M to 1M but the CPU and duration are increased.
- I'm trying to understand the behavior and what is best here.

Query:

```
set statistics time, io on;
select 
    min(CampaignID), 
    max(CampaignID) 
from Campaign
where datecreated < dateadd(day, -90, getutcdate())
go
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCIX] 
ON [dbo].[Campaign](DateCreated)
INCLUDE (Campaignid)
go
select 
    min(CampaignID), 
    max(CampaignID) 
from Campaign with (index = NCIX)
where datecreated < dateadd(day, -90, getutcdate())
set statistics time, io off;
```

Messages:

```
(1 row affected)
Table 'Campaign'. Scan count 2, logical reads 3548070, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(8 rows affected)

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 14546 ms,  elapsed time = 14723 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 3 ms.

(1 row affected)
Table 'Campaign'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1191017, physical reads 0, page server reads 0, read-ahead reads 19, page server read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob page server reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0, lob page server read-ahead reads 0.

(6 rows affected)

(1 row affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 163953 ms,  elapsed time = 164163 ms.
```

Execution plans:

[image: Query1 execution plan]

[image: Query2 execution plan]

[Complete execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1CkkcBtt)

Comment: There is no "best". There are scenarios when one performs better and there are others when the other one.

In your example the scan is faster and SQL Server is using that, because it knows (guesses correctly), that it will require less effort to scan the tables than to search using the index, then look up all the matching records. We don't know your index, we don't know your data, hard to tell anything else. In my experience, the best is to let SQL Server choose in most cases. You can help, but I would not go with an index hint.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely consider your inputs. But to your ask I have included the index definition to get a batter picture of my ask.

Comment: Any thoughts about the logical reads here? the sql server chosen one is doing 3.5M logical reads where the one with index hint is taking 1.1M logical reads.

Comment: The index is nice to have, with that, I can say that SQL Server either queries the index in the order of dates and most probably get most/lots of the records, then needs to sort (aggregate) for the ID to get the MIN and MAX. The other option is to go through the data on the clustered index and just fetch the ID in order (I assume, your clustered index key is the ID). The second one is faster when the number of records matching your where condition is close to the total number of records.

Comment: Just to see what I am talking about, lets create your index like this: `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCIX] 
ON [dbo].[Campaign](Campaignid)
INCLUDE (DateCreated)` and see what is the page count when this index is forced

Comment: sure, let me check that.

Comment: A good way to share execution plans is by uploading to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the links to your question. Images of the plan don't the the whole story.

Comment: Thank you @DanGuzman for sharing that. I will update my post shortly as mentioned.

Comment: @Pred The second approach is much faster and less resource intense. I'm definitely going with that approach. Here is what I'm seeing with it 
`logical reads 32950, 'CPU time = 1515 ms,  elapsed time = 1784 ms.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no 'best' operator. Sometimes reading more data is more efficient than reading some data and massage them to get our results. 'Best' as almost everything is relative.

Lets try to understand what happened in the comments...

The query

```
select 
    min(CampaignID), 
    max(CampaignID) 
from Campaign
where datecreated < dateadd(day, -90, getutcdate())
```

Which says:

> I want the first and the last ID (min/max) of any record where the date is less than a constant date.

**Clustered**

The first query without the index/index hint did what SQL Server thought is cheaper than reading any index even if it requires more IO (disk usage). This is because finding the minimum and maximum while validating the records in the table is cheaper than selecting half of the table, then reordering/aggregating them find the exact same info.

The clustered index stores all data on disk and is logically ordered by the key columns, in this case CampaignID (I assume). This means, that to find the minimum and maximum ID is easy: The minimum is the first ID which matches the criteria -> lets check each ID from the first one and stop once we find a record where the date is in place (this will most probably be the first one). The maximum is the first record matching the condition from the end of the index.

**Index with the date as key**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCIX] 
ON [dbo].[Campaign](DateCreated)
INCLUDE (Campaignid)
```

With the first index (date as the key column), SQL Server can use the date to filter the data, true, but it did not help in sorting. It still has to check every record in that index and figure out the minimum and maximum from a possibly unordered set of values.

**Index with the ID as key**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCIX] 
ON [dbo].[Campaign](Campaignid)
INCLUDE (DateCreated)
```

With the second index where the ID was the key column, SQL Server can use the same trick as with the clustered key. The only difference is that there is no other data to read, but the ID and the date, which is much smaller than the whole record would be, therefore it can fit in less pages and requires less IO.

SQL Server will most probably choose the second index even if there is no index hint.

**How the second index works (approximation by query)**

You can get the minimum Campaignid by

```
SELECT TOP(1)
  Campaignid
FROM
  [dbo].[Campaign]
WHERE
  datecreated < dateadd(day, -90, getutcdate())
ORDER BY
  Campaignid ASC
```

and the maximum with a very similar query

```
SELECT TOP(1)
  Campaignid
FROM
  [dbo].[Campaign]
WHERE
  datecreated < dateadd(day, -90, getutcdate())
ORDER BY
  Campaignid DESC
```

If you cross join them as subqueries, you pretty much got what the execution plan describes.

**Notes**

Here I would add a note: optimizing for only one query is not always the best tactic. You can't optimize for everything, if this query runs once a day/week/quarter, that 14-15 seconds runtime with the clustered key will most probably do no harm. If the index does not help other queries, I would not create it, unless it is a mission critical query.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation for this. This particular query in our environment runs daily and the impact we are seeing is for other calls that are trying to access during that period. Hope this helps to solve that.

Comment: @SivaDasari Since your query is using DATE (and does not care about time), you can run this at midnight once and store the results somewhere, then reuse those results the whole day.